# Changing screen resolution without seeing the screen?

Tags: boot, display, display-resolution, intel, 32-bit

So I rediscovered an old 32-bit Wintel PC that was sitting in my basement. Only problem: the hard drive had been wiped, and there was no Windows. Naturally, I decided to run it on 32-bit Ubuntu 16.04.

After creating DVD install media and installing it to the computer, I booted in for the first time without the install media. Then, I got hit with the "Mode Not Supported" on my monitor. I'm confident that I did the download properly, and the computer is still running, but nothing is showing up.

This brings me to my question: how can I change my screen resolution without seeing anything on my screen? The "mode not supported" means that the screen is outputting something, but my monitor can't even tell me what resolution it is for some reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The easiest solution is, may be, to get another monitor. Lower frequency/resolution, then try again with the old monitor.

Comment: This sounds very much link an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Are you sure you actually installed the operating system to disk, and that your motherboard BIOS is booting to the device where you installed Ubuntu?  If you can't get past this block, why don't you just try to reinstall the OS again -- perhaps review some installation guides here or elsewhere first?

Comment: @Nmath I have installed it correctly, and it was showing an output throughout the download process. It worked right up until it told me to eject the CD and hit Enter to reboot. Then it began displaying an "unsupported mode". So the image must be on the hard drive now.

Comment: If it was installed correctly, it would survive the first reboot.  Can you enter GRUB during boot by holding ESC or SHIFT?  Using GRUB to boot into recovery  would be one way to rescue a broken system, but why even go through that effort when you've never even used this installation.  I suggest trying again.  At the very least, upload a picture of this error you are getting, to see if it even has anything to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: On second thought , it might not be an Ubuntu issue at all. I just created a Windows XP install media, and it went into the same unsupported mode. My monitor might be too new for 20-year-old PC shenanigans.